# Scraping LinkedIn company name, location and followers from HTML script

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, linkedin-api

I'm able to scrape the company's name, location. Using the code below. But I'm facing difficulty to scrape the number of followers

Here is the HTML script for reference.

```
<div class="block mt2">
<div>
<h1 class="ember-view t-24 t-black t-bold full-width" id="ember28" title="Pacific Retail Capital Partners">
<span dir="ltr">Pacific Retail Capital Partners</span>
</h1>
<p class="org-top-card-summary__tagline t-16 t-black">
      Our decades of experience and innovative strategies are transforming retail-led centers into high-performing properties.
    </p>
<!-- -->
<div class="org-top-card-summary-info-list t-14 t-black--light">
<div class="org-top-card-summary-info-list__info-item">
      Leasing Non-residential Real Estate
    </div>
<!-- -->
<div class="inline-block">
<div class="org-top-card-summary-info-list__info-item">
        El Segundo, CA
      </div>
<!-- -->
<div class="org-top-card-summary-info-list__info-item">
          4,047 followers
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Scrapping company's name was easy and direct

```
info_div = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'block mt2'})
#print(info_div)
info_name = info_div.find_all('h1')
company_name = info_name[0].get_text().strip()
print(company_name, type(company_name),len(company_name))
```

Company location was accessed using this.

```
info_block = info_div.find_all('div', {'class' : 'inline-block'})
info_loc = info_block[0].find('div', {'class' : 'org-top-card-summary-info-list__info-item'}).get_text().strip()
print(info_loc)
```

How can I scrape/access  second element i.e. 4047 followers ?

Comment: 'soup.find' is not Selenium command..

Comment: Did you get the output you needed from the answer I provided?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the contains operator within the CSS selector, in this case we're searching for followers in a div with the specified class name:

```
followers_div = soup.select_one('.org-top-card-summary-info-list__info-item:contains(followers)')
```

This returns:

```
<div class="org-top-card-summary-info-list__info-item">
          4,047 followers
        </div>
```